# What is the null hypothesis in a multivariate Granger causality test (MVGC) test?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, multivariate-analysis, granger-causality

What is the null hypothesis in a multivariate Granger causality test?

Is it that one series does not cause any of the n-series, or that n-series do not cause one particular series?

---

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967016/multivariate-grangers-causality describes how to implement the software. I have no idea what these software do.
Maybe https://arxiv.org/pdf/1002.0299.pdf explains it better, but I have no idea what the null hypothesis of MVGC from it.

Comment: *Granger* is a surname, so it is spelled with a capital *G*.

Comment: Can you define *multivariate Granger causality test* precisely? This term may have slightly different meanings depending on who is using it.

Comment: I meant cointegration test.

Comment: That confuses me even more. Granger causality and cointegration are different things. Could you elaborate?

Comment: cointegration suggests granger causality.